# MATLAB scripts to be run on Flask backend: matlab to .py converter?

Tags: python, matlab, flask

I have a Flask backend which receives xml data from the front, which i then parse at the back to feed to a number of pre-provided MATLAB scripts. My issue is both architectural and functional in that:

(1)i'd like to know how to hook up multiple inter-dependent MATLAB scripts to a Flask server for those scripts to operate on POST requests to the server (be it some sort of middleware between matlab and python or matlab custom util)

(2)and how to dynamically change the directory from which my main MATLAB script imports the file that it is supposed to analyze given that it is an incoming request,

Stack recommends a variety of things, most frequent being the SMOP library for converting MATLAB into python by the great victorlei, but this doesn't seem to do the trick for the scripts of the given complexity: there are roughly 5 .m files worth of dependencies and not all needed classes are implemented

My copy of Matlab application compiler does not have the "python package" option either.

**Here is a sample of MATLAB the code**: it's one file of a package with subdirectories(you can see dependencies imported from the relative path). It accepts a single .m5 file as an input. How does one go about implementing something like this on a server?

```
% calculate the VCG ECG CAD Score form the 12 lead ECG
%
% input path to file
% output size 1 by 1

function [Score] = Calculate_VCG_CAD_Score_From12LeadECGTemplate(TwelveLeadECGFilePath, VCG_transform)

% testing
Testing = 1;

% addpaths
root = 'M:\Some Dingy Ass School in Europe\Datenbank';
addpath([root,'\Software\Matlab']);
addpath([root,'\Software\Matlab\Transforms']);
addpath([root,'\Cleverly Editted Out Projectname\ProgrammCode\Gui']);

% warnings
war1 = 'no file name given';
war2 = 'Undefined transform. Averdson is used';

if nargin < 1
    warning(war1)
    TwelveLeadECGFilePath = [root,'\Cleverly Editted Out Projectname\Daten\ECG\CS200Ex_BaselVIII_2703_3212\MPS_2703_2703_20140228_082204000.xml']
    warning(war2)
    VCG_transform = 'Averdson';
end
if nargin == 1
    warning(war2)
    VCG_transform = 'Averdson';
end
if nargin > 2
    warning('too many inputs will be ignored');
end

% select transform
switch(VCG_transform)
    case {'Averdson'} 
        transform = 'Averdson';
    otherwise
        warning(war2)
        transform = 'Averdson';
end

cebrisDataReader(TwelveLeadECGFilePath);

% read in ECG file (XML, Templates)
% evtl. Funktion machen
%xDoc = xmlread(TwelveLeadECGFilePath);
%xRoot = xDoc.getDocumentElement;
%schema = char(xRoot.getAttribute('xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation'))
%allListitems = xDoc.getElementsByTagName('listitem')

% test case
TwelveLeadECGTemplateRest = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24; 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36];
TwelveLeadECGTemplateRest = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2; 
                             2 4 6 8 10 12 14 12 10 8 6 4; 
                             3 6 8 10 12 14 16 14 12 10 8 6;
                             2 4 6 8 10 12 14 12 10 8 6 4; 
                             1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2];

% Fall 1 keine CAD
TwelveLeadECGTemplateMaxLoad = TwelveLeadECGTemplateRest;
figure(2);clf
subplot(2,1,1); hold on
plot(TwelveLeadECGTemplateRest(:,1),'b-');
plot(TwelveLeadECGTemplateRest(:,2),'g-');
plot(TwelveLeadECGTemplateRest(:,3),'r-');
subplot(2,1,2); hold on
plot(TwelveLeadECGTemplateMaxLoad(:,1),'b-');
plot(TwelveLeadECGTemplateMaxLoad(:,2),'g-');
plot(TwelveLeadECGTemplateMaxLoad(:,3),'r-');
%figure(3);clf
%plot3(TwelveLeadECGTemplateRest(1,:),TwelveLeadECGTemplateRest(2,:),TwelveLeadECGTemplateRest(3,:),'b-');
%hold on
%plot3(TwelveLeadECGTemplateMaxLoad(1,:),TwelveLeadECGTemplateMaxLoad(2,:),TwelveLeadECGTemplateMaxLoad(3,:),'r-');

% calculate VCG from 12 leadd ECG
if Testing
    TwelveLeadECGTemplateRest = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1; 
                                 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2; 
                                 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3;
                                 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4; 
                                 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5];
end
[VCG_rest] = TwelveLeadECGToVCG(TwelveLeadECGTemplateRest, transform);
[VCG_MaxLoad] = TwelveLeadECGToVCG(TwelveLeadECGTemplateMaxLoad, transform);
if Testing
    VCG_rest
end

% calculate area from 
if Testing
    VCG_rest = [0 0 1 2 3 2 1;
                0 1 2 2 0 2 -1;
                0 1 2 3 4 2 1];
    VCG_rest = VCG_rest'
    VCG_MaxLoad = [0 0.5 1 2 3 2 1;
                   0 0.5 1 2 0 2 -1;
                   0 0.5 1 3 4 2 1];
    VCG_MaxLoad = VCG_MaxLoad'
end
VCGAreaRest = CalculateVCGScore(VCG_rest);
VCGAreaMaxLoad = CalculateVCGScore(VCG_MaxLoad);
if Testing
    VCGAreaRest
    VCGAreaMaxLoad
end

figure(4);clf
subplot(2,1,1)
hold on
plot(VCGAreaRest,'b-');
plot(VCGAreaMaxLoad,'r-');
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(VCGAreaRest-VCGAreaMaxLoad,'k-');

figure(5);clf
plot3(VCG_rest(1,:),VCG_rest(2,:),VCG_rest(3,:),'b-');
hold on
plot3(VCG_MaxLoad(1,:),VCG_MaxLoad(2,:),VCG_MaxLoad(3,:),'r-');

end

% locally defined functions

function [VCGarea] = CalculateVCGScore(VCGTemplate)

    LengthOfTemplate = size(VCGTemplate,1);
    area = 0;
    VCGarea = [];
    for n = 2: LengthOfTemplate
        % cumulative
        area = area + 0.5*norm(cross(VCGTemplate(n,:), VCGTemplate(n-1,:))); 
        % partly areas
        area = 0.5*norm(cross(VCGTemplate(n,:), VCGTemplate(n-1,:))); 

        % store
        VCGarea(n-1,:) = area;
    end
    % close loop (first and last element should be null as (0,0,0) for n=0
    VCGarea(LengthOfTemplate,:) = norm(cross(VCGTemplate(LengthOfTemplate,:), VCGTemplate(1,:)));
end
```

Back-end server is standard Flask, i guess it would qualify as a RESTful API at this point, but i have only picked up the concept last week so not sure. Bare bones of it look like this right now:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask import jsonify
import requests, os, json, xmltodict
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
CORS(app)
#VCG scripts are under Software/Matlab/Transfroms

@app.route('/api/upload', methods = ['POST'])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['file']    
    contents = xmltodict.parse(file)
    # xmltodict is XML to JSON parser
    print(">> The XML contents. <<<\n")
    return jsonify(contents)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)

# ----> Matlab to Python Scripts
# ---->Upload File parser
```

I would be happy to hear any and all suggestions! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some code, otherwise it is hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not work with the XML data directly in MATLAB? [xml2struct](https://github.com/acampb311/xml2struct) is an awesome/fast MEX function for converting XML files into MATLAB structs. There is a [non-MEX version of this in the File Exchange by Wouter Foukena](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct) that I've benched on my own machine as running about 130x slower than the C++ MEX.

Or if I read this wrong and you need to read JSON and not XML in MATLAB (I read your post as your process reads in XML and outputs JSON), try [jsonlab](https://github.com/fangq/jsonlab). Its output is a little different (cells/arrays instead of struct) but still easy to work with.